# How to add regularization to simplex solver

Tags: optimization, simplex

How to express L1 / L2 regularization as a constraint for the simplex solver?

When optimizing functions with linear relationships, one common method is the [simplex solver](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Simplex_algorithm).

If there are several optimal solutions, the solver stops when it reaches the first. I am looking at a case where there are several solutions that are good and I would like to penalize giving large weights to any one solution.

In e.g. OLS, L1 or L2 regularization would be used to achieve this but I am not sure how to include such a constraint so that it has the desired effect.

Take for example that we are minimizing the following
$$
10 x + 0.5 y + 0.5 z
$$
with the constraints
$$
x + y <= 0.9
$$ $$
x + y + z = 1
$$

Solving this leads to either y or z = 0.9. How to enforce a constraint that penalizes large variables? (I.e. still prevents y - 0.9 when the relation is $10x + 0.55y + 0.5 x$)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add a term that penalizes the largest value $x_i$. I.e.

$$
\begin{align}
 & \min c^Tx + p \cdot z\\
 & z \ge x_i \>\> \forall i\\
\end{align}
$$